# StencilJS Web Component: How to allow end-user to prevent default via custom click event?

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

Example [Stencil.js](https://stenciljs.com/) web component:

```
import { Component, ComponentInterface, Event, EventEmitter, h, Host } from "@stencil/core";

@Component({
    tag: 'foo-testwebcomponent'
})
export class TestWebComponent implements ComponentInterface {
    @Event({
        eventName: 'foo-click',
        cancelable: true
    }) fooClick: EventEmitter;
    fooClickHandler() {
        this.fooClick.emit();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Host>
                <a href="#"
                   onClick={this.fooClickHandler.bind(this)}
                >Testing</a>
            </Host>
        )
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<foo-testwebcomponent id="test"></foo-testwebcomponent>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById('test')
            .addEventListener('foo-click', event => {
              event.preventDefault();
              console.log(`Foo Test Web Component clicked!`);
            });
  });
</script>
```

**Problem:**

In the HTML implementation, the prevent default does not stop the link from working.

**Question:**

How can I allow the end-user of my web component to prevent default, and stop the link from working?

I know that I can add `preventDefault()` in the `fooClickHandler()` (see below), but that seems odd to me. I'd like to give the control to the end user of the web component.

```
@Event({
  eventName: 'foo-click',
  cancelable: true
}) fooClick: EventEmitter<MouseEvent>;
fooClickHandler(event: MouseEvent) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.fooClick.emit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate events:

1. The user-initiated click event
2. Your `fooClick` custom event

In your example you call `preventDefault()` on the custom event but you need to call it on the original click event to prevent the link from navigating.

I know of two ways to achieve this:

**1: Track whether your custom event is canceled**

You can check whether the user called `preventDefault()` on your custom event using the `defaultPrevented` property. The `fooClick` event handler can stay the same.

```
fooClickHandler(clickEvent: MouseEvent) {
  const customEvent = this.fooClick.emit();
  if (customEvent.defaultPrevented) {
    clickEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Check out [this online demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/w5kmNkHabqSCaPG1Tj5m/src/index.tsx).

**2: Pass the click event**

Pass the click event to the `fooClick` event handler so the user can cancel it.

```
fooClickHandler(clickEvent: MouseEvent) {
  this.fooClick.emit({ originalEvent: clickEvent });
}
```

And in the handler:

```
element.addEventListener('foo-click', event => {
  event.detail.originalEvent.preventDefault();
  console.log(`Foo Test Web Component clicked!`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I like both examples. I actually ran across `customEvent.defaultPrevented`, but I was not sure how to use that to prevent the `href` from firing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to overload the `addEventListener` function and capture the function **reference**

(needs some more work to make it work with nested elements, you get drift)

Or use a custom method `addClick(name,func)` so the user can still add any listener

```html
<script>
  customElements.define(
    "my-element",
    class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.clicked = (evt)=>{
          document.body.append("component handler")
        }
        this.onclick = (evt) => {
            this.clicked(evt);
        }
      }
      addEventListener(name, func) {
        this.clicked = func;
      }
    }
  );
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector('my-element')
      .addEventListener('click', event => {
        document.body.append(`user handler`);
      });
  });
</script>
<my-element>Hello Web Components World!</my-element>
```

You could also use good old `onevent` handlers:

```html
<script>
  customElements.define(
    "my-element",
    class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.onclick = (evt) => console.log("component handler")
      }
    }
  );
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let el = document.querySelector('my-element');
    el.onclick = event => console.log(`user handler`, el.onclick);
  });
</script>
<my-element onclick="console.log('inline')">Hello Web Components World!</my-element>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it! +1